# Not able to catch slot color values in rasa

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

Hi I am not able to catch slot values in my custom action I have made a custom action that returns a slot set of the clinks ie. links that are correspoding to colors like red blue or black The clinks is a list of dict.Here is my run method

```
    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain): 
        clinks = [ {“color”: “red”,“link”:“Amazon.com: red shirts”}, {“color”: “blue”, “link”: “Amazon.com: blue shirts”}, {“color”:“black”,“link”:“Amazon.com: black shirts”} ] 
        color = tracker.get_slot(“color”)
        print(color) 
        link = [c[“link”] for c in clinks if c[“color”] == color] 
        print(link)

    dispatcher.utter_message("{}".format(link))
    return [SlotSet("clinks", clinks)]
```

I am using spacy pipeline But the output of server shows that value of slot is None How to solve this problem

Comment: Can you tell us what value you are getting from `tracker.get_slot("color")`. Also has the slot been set prior to this action getting called?

Comment: Sir i have solved the problem, first i was getting None slot values because i was not entering the correct stories.md now its working